# Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\java

Tags: java, batch-file

when i tried to execute batchfile at cmd prompt its showing following error.This is my code..when i tried its showing Could not find or load main class C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\java
can you expain me why this error is coming

```
    @echo off
    rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    rem Configuration wizard Script for Win32
    rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto winnt
    echo This script only works with NT-based versions of Windows.
    goto :eof

    :winnt

    set DIRNAME=.\
    if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" set DIRNAME=%~dp0%
    set PROGNAME=configwizard.bat
    if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" set PROGNAME=%~nx0%

    pushd %DIRNAME%..
    set DCM_HOME=%CD%
    popd

    set PROJECT_LIB=%DCM_HOME%\lib
    IF "%PATH%" == "" GOTO NOPATH
    :YESPATH
    @ECHO The PATH environment variable was detected.
    PATH=%PROJECT_LIB%;%PATH%
    GOTO END
    :NOPATH
    @ECHO The PATH environment variable was NOT detected.
    :END
    set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
    set JAVA_OPTS= -Dlog4j.configuration="file:%DCM_HOME%\conf\cw-log4j.properties"
    set JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -Xms768m
    set JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx1024m
    set JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    set CW_CLASSPATH="%PROJECT_LIB%\diffutils-1.2.1.jar;%PROJECT_LIB%\log4j-    1.2.16.jar;%PROJECT_LIB%\postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar;%PROJECT_LIB%\super-csv-2.2.0.jar;%PROJECT_LIB%\util.jar;%PROJECT_LIB%\version-1.1.jar"
    set CW_CMD="%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java" -cp %CW_CLASSPATH%  com.xyz.yyz.DatabaseComparator
     "Java" %CW_CMD%
      pause
```

thanks in advance

Comment: at first glance `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\java`  does not seem to be a class name, rather than that the path to `java.exe`

Comment: I tried to execute like that also but same error is comming. i did in this way too C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java or java.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to my comment, try to replace

```
"Java" %CW_CMD%
```

with

```
call %CW_CMD%
```

since you already set the path to java.exe in `CW_CMD` there is no need for the first `"Java"`

Comment: @user3912803 this error has no longer to do with your question, you're now able to run your script successfully and this is what you have asked for. If you have any other problems please try to post another question.

Comment: @user3912803 ... and to briefly address this error, you have a broken log4j configuration. An appender for the logger `com.brocade.comparator.util.Utilities` could not be found. You need to refer to log4j manual in order to configure it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud remove "Java" in "Java" %CW_CMD%

```
%CW_CMD%
pause
```

You should also remove line

```
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mentioned com.xyz.yyz.DatabaseComparator in environment variable path ?. If not, Please mention it in path variable and try to execute the batch file.

Comment: i have set in class path %PROJECT_LIB%\version-1.1.jar